# urxvt remapping Shift-PgUp/Shift-PgDown to Shift-Control-PgUp/PgDown

Tags: urxvt

has someone experience in configuring urxvt? I'm trying to figure out how to remap shift-page_up/down to control-shift-page_up/down. I figured out how to use eval perl script's scroll_down_pages/scroll_up_pages functions for that which works but beside the fact that scroll_down_pages functions isn't properly implemented and needs to be patched I do not want to use perl for such simple operations. Any ideas how to do it correctly?

my keybindings

```
! Keybindings
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-C: eval:selection_to_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-V: eval:paste_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down: command:\033]721;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-Up: eval:scroll_up_pages 1
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-Down: eval:scroll_down_pages 1
!Rxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-Up: command:\033[5~   <- some of my failed attempts
!Rxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-Down: command:\033[6~ <- some of my failed attempts
URxvt.iso14755: False
```

I cannot use 'command:\033]721;n\007' instead because n should be equal to the size of the viewable area which is not known a priory